# How to reference to an instance created in KV file

Tags: python, kivy, instance

I want to call a method `add_category_to_tree()` from `TreeCategory` class, when pressing SAVE button in `AddCategoryPopup` class. However, I have problems how to reference to the TreeCategory instance, which is created in KV file.
I was trying to search solution, but nothing works. Currently i get  `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'` error.

How should I do this properly ? Thank you for help

```
class TreeCategory(TreeView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeCategory, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_category_to_tree(self, name):
        self.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text = name.upper()))


class AddCategoryPopup(Popup):

    def save(self):
        self.ids.tree.add_category_to_tree(self.ids.entry.text) # ????
        db.adding_to_db('kategorie', 'nazwa', self.ids.entry.text)
        self.dismiss()

    def close(self):
        self.dismiss()

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    tree = ObjectProperty(None)

    def add_category_button(self):
        popup = AddCategoryPopup(title = 'Dodawanie nowej kategorii')
        return popup.open()


class GuiCookBookApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Książka kucharska"
        return MainScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = DatabaseManager("cookbook.sqlite")
    GuiCookBookApp().run()
```

KV file:

```
<AddCategoryPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            multiline: False
            hint_text: 'Podaj nazwę kategorii...'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: 'SAVE'
                on_press: root.save()
            Button:
                text: 'CANCEL'
                on_press: root.close()

<MainScreen>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    display: entry
    tree: tree

    BoxLayout:
        id: menu
        size_hint_y: .1

        Button:
            text: 'Dodaj kategorię'
            on_press: root.add_category_button()

    BoxLayout:
        id: recipe_view
        orientation: "horizontal"

        TreeCategory:
            id: tree
            hide_root: True
            size_hint: .25, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `self.ids` in Python you can only access the  ids in KV from that particular class. So `self.ids.tree` is only possible inside the `MainScreen` class in Python not in the `AddCategoryPopup` class.

You could create an `ObjectProperty` 'topwidget' in your `AddCategoryPopup` rule and pass in the Main class when you instantiate the popup. Something like:

```
popup = AddCategoryPopup(topwidget=self)
```

Then in the 'save' method of your custom popup class you can do something like:

```
self.topwidget.tree...
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation :) now I understand how it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite a few ways. For instance you can put the .kv in your main .py file.

```
w = Builder.load_string('''
Widget:
    height: self.width / 2. if self.disabled else self.width
    x: self.y + 50
''')
```

https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.builder.html

You can simply name the .kv file

```
guicookbookapp.kv
```

and leave it in the root directory of your project.

https://kivy.org/docs/examples/gen__application__app_with_kv__py.html

You can also add the following

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_file('guicookbookapp.kv')
```

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.